# What would keep a hypothetical fusion reactor from "igniting the atmosphere"?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

So in the early days of Nuclear fission, there was a concern about the resulting energy igniting the atmosphere in a ball of fire and world-wide death which is <s>awesome</s> <s>terrifying</s> awesomely terrifying. This of course did not happen, and I'm led to believe that these concerns ran along the same vein as concerns raised about the LHC creating a black-hole that would consume the earth (read; sensationalist media fueled, the scientific community at large had no reason to believe this would actually happen).

To my understanding, fusion reactions generate orders of magnitude more energy than fission reactions. It's fairly obvious that hydrogen fusion is self-sustaining in the right environment (see exhibit A - The Sun), and elements up to iron release energy when fusing, so that includes most of our atmosphere. What reason is there to believe that successful achieving fusion in the confines of our atmosphere would not, y'know, set it on fire?

Comment: There is a critical density that needs to be achieved to sustain fusion reactions

Comment: For the atmosphere to burn like that, you'd need a *lot* of fuel.

Comment: Also see [Can Jupiter be ignited?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/776/can-jupiter-be-ignited)

Comment: The problem is that if fusion were to start somewhere it would cause a blast wave that would blow away the surrounding atmosphere. So, you need to contain the atmosphere, Earth's gravity isn't sufficient for that.

Comment: Not an answer on "why", but there were several detonations of H-bombs, surely exceeding the energy density of any fusion reactor by several orders of magnitude, and, causing damage more than enough, but all were far away from any runaway effect.