# How much more mass would Jupiter have to accrete to start fusion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, fusion, jupiter

How long would it take? Is it likely in the life of our sun?

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/776/

Comment: Arthur C Clarke's book 2010 talks about that. I wonder how accurate that is?