# Could you use the detonation of a Hydrogen bomb or atomic bomb to start a nuclear fusion reactor

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering, explosions

Would this lead to a reactor that produced more energy than you put in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What stops us from creating a nuclear fusion reactor as we already have the hydrogen bomb working on the same principle of fusion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330349/)

Comment: No I'm saying could we use the h bomb as the input energy for a nuclear fusion reactor

Comment: How do you stop the bomb from blowing up your reactor? How would you refuel it? But anyway, starting the fusion reaction isn't the hardest part. The problem is sustaining and controlling it.

Answer (score 3):

This has actually been proposed! [Project PACER](http://www.ralphmoir.com/pacer/) at Los Alamos explored the possibility of detonating hydrogen bombs in underground cavities (e.g. in salt domes) to produce "geothermal" energy. Exploding a 2 kton device once every 20 minutes in a steel lined underground cavity using molten salt droplets to cushion the effects of the explosive would produce about 1000 MWe of power. This is a fusion reactor since most energy comes from the fusion reaction, started by a nuclear detonation.

Comment: The fact that someone *proposes* an idea does not make it in any way sensible.  How many active projects to *build* such a device are under way ?  A 2kT explosion *every twenty minutes* ?  Doesn't that sound just the tiniest bit crackpot to you ?

Comment: @StephenG - Peer reviewed publications. Check the calculations, they made sense to me. I would expect it to be very impractical, but the question was never if using bombs to power reactors was a *good* solution to energy production, just if it was possible.

Comment: No argument about the source you link to (good find, BTW), however peer reviewed, while a better gauge for quality material, does not make an idea sensible.  The OP asked about power production and that, to me, means practical.  Strictly speaking the OP asked if more energy is produced than you put in and, again strictly speaking, the answer to that is *no*.  It only makes sense as a question if you're considering the practicality of it all (IMO).

Comment: @StephenG - More energy DOES come out. Strictly speaking, the answer is absolutely *yes*. What are you talking about?

Comment: And as to "practical", well you only know that if you try. Some chunk of LLNL was working on this under Plowshares to the point they carried out actual UGX's to test it. I don't know why you would call this crackpot. A good portion of LLNL also worked on mirror fusion, it didn't work in the end either, are you saying Post is a crackpot too?

Answer (score 2):

I think this confuses what is hard about getting fusion reactors to work.

I assume you are thinking of using a thermonuclear device to *start* a fusion reactor rather than to use one or more *as* a fusion reactor.  In other words I assume you are not thinking of harnessing the energy released from one or more such devices as in the various mad schemes people involved with nuclear weapons thought up to harness them for peaceful power generation.  That approach is addressed in another answer.

The problem with getting a fusion reactor to work is not getting fusion started (anyone can do that): it is keeping the stuff you are fusing stable and contained for long enough that you can get more power out than you put in.  There are various approaches to doing this of which we know of only one really successful one: that approach – gravitational confinement – unfortunately doesn't scale down to scales we can use directly.

Given that the problem is not starting fusion but containing it and keeping it stable, it seems unlikely that detonating a thermonuclear weapon inside your fusion reactor is going to help!