# Nobel Prize in Physics 2019 on exoplanets and Hot Jupiters

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, astrophysics, astronomy

The **51 Pegasi b**, discovered by Didier Queloz and Michel Mayor  is classified as a hot Jupiter and not considered to be a star. I had read a bit about the minimum mass necessary for being a brown dwarf at some 13 Jovian masses, also the following question "[Can Jupiter be ignited?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/776/227794)" which has an answer stating that clear boundaries have not been drawn regarding *gas giants* and *brown dwarfs*. My question is how was it concluded that a *Hot Jupiter* different is from star types like brown dwarfs, in the sense that they could assert it wasn't a star they were observing ( keeping in mind the possibility of more massive ones like **WASP-18-B** (*around 10 Jovian masses*)).

Specifically how does one eliminate the possibility that it could have been a star at the end of its life-cycle for we could have considered it to be a smaller star of a binary system (considering the case of distance to be pretty close to the central star) ?

Apologies if the question sounds too naive.

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/305797/fulltext/36734.text.html. This would be good to look at, I guess, regarding the possibility of nuclear reactions inside Jupiter. Also considering brown dwarf stars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf), which is not expected to have conventional nuclear reactions. Please do correct me if I am mistaken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not naive at all, don't worry.

51 Peg b has been found via the [radial velocity method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_spectroscopy). Upon detection, this method automatically gives a minimum mass of the companion, which is $M_{\rm min} = M \; \sin(i)$, where $M$ is the unknown actual planetary mass and $i$ is the (generally) unknown inclination of the orbit towards the observer.

It was determined that $M_{\rm min}\approx 0.5 M_{\rm Jup}$, and for isotropically distributed orientations of orbits on the sky, the expectation value of $\sin(i)$ is about unity. Extremal values of $i$ that would make $\sin(i) \ll 1$ and thus $M \gg M_{\rm Jup}$, are improbable, but not excluded. In their paper, Mayor & Queloz cite a $1\%$ chance that the planet is above $4 M_{\rm Jup}$ and $1/40.000$ that it is above the deuterium-burning limit of $13 M_{\rm Jup}$.
Thus it was concluded that an object of about Jupiter-mass was found.

That this object is also a planet stems from the difficulty of making a stellar companion (typical binary stars have about equal mass, but ratios of up to a factor of 10 are normal), and then evaporating it enough to loose not 100% of the mass, but just about 99%, which is another improbable mechanism.

Considering the last part of your question, stars don't just become 'small' at the end of their lives. Stars with significant mass-loss at the end of their lives loose this mass via strong stellar winds, which a) leave very visible [planetary nebulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_nebula) (which is absent in 51 Peg) and again b) leaving such a small blob of mass (compared to a hypothetical progenitor star) of a tiny fraction of the original mass is improbable, or even impossible (strong winds cease to exist at certain stellar masses/radii).

Comment: One doubt: How do we consider the above question for a more massive planet, like WASP-18b and the like?

Comment: @Maan: Well, if something like WASP-18b would have been the first HJ to be discovered, the scientific impact and the planetary nature might have been less clear. WASP-18b is a transiting planet (and was discovered as such), so it became clear that $\sin(i)=1$, and thus there was no doubt in the mass, which was only measured post-discovery. Another hypothetical $10 M_{\rm Jup}$ planet that is non-transiting would have had a realistic chance of being above the deuterium burning limit, as $sin(i)$ would be unknown then.

Comment: @Maan: The issue with binary star formation is, that the less massive the companion is, the more one runs into a fine-tuning problem of explaining those low masses via cloud fragmentation. This was maybe still a discussion point at the time, but nowadays we know from statistics that a) around 1% of all stars have hot Jupiters (waaaay to much for fragmentation scenarios) and b) there is a 'brown dwarf desert', which is a gap in number populations as function of mass that clearly separates stars and planets, see also fig. 8 in this important article: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0412356